# How to run Selenium through xvfb? (X frame virtual buffer)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, firefoxdriver, xvfb

*Somewhat [specific](https://askubuntu.com/a/773384/45156) to `Ubuntu`, this is towards running [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/28603/8900) `JAR` on a server.*

Running `xvfb` just [hangs for me](https://askubuntu.com/q/934562/45156), so trying to get the syntax properly:

```
thufir@doge:~/.html$ 
thufir@doge:~/.html$ xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 --server-args='-screen 0, 1024x768x24' firefox -start-maximized http://www.google.com > /dev/null &
[5] 2485
thufir@doge:~/.html$
```

so that at least some output is captured, ie:  `foo.html` or such.  I've tried redirecting to a file but can't seem to get any output from `xvfb` with the above usage.

in larger the context of running `selenium` from the CLI as so:

```
java -jar NetBeansProjects/selenium/build/libs/selenium-all.jar
```

How do I execute the `JAR` so that it's purely a CLI operation?

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/7568899/262852

https://stackoverflow.com/q/16726227/262852

http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless